# GOOGLE ACTION: Changing default text for SignIn() prompt

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to change the default text that triggers when the SignIn() helper intent is invoked. Here is my current code triggering the helper intent:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
   conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});
```

Here is what is currently being prompted by the Google Action:

> To get your account details, you’ll need an account with App. 
>   To create a new one for you, I’ll just need some info. If you
>   want more details, say "Tell me more. " So, can I ask Google for your
>   name, email address, and profile picture?

Is there a way to override the default prompt that is provided by Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do that. For permissions and other features like SigniIn(), you cannot change the default response. However, you may add some to the existing response but that is also available to some permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your input, sincerely appreciate it!